# Optimizing query execution time with may INSERT statements for Azure

Tags: sql, azure, optimization

**Context:**

Execution time is now 2 minutes. I use Azure with Elastic database 50 eDTUs

**Question**:

Is any way to speed up this query? I try Index on `#ActualValuesLines` , UNION instead of `INSERT INTO` but the time still remaining 2 minutes.

```sql
DECLARE @RoNo int
CREATE TABLE #ReportValues(Position int, Col nvarchar(100), Amount decimal(28, 10))

CREATE TABLE #ActualValuesLines 
(Amount decimal(28,10),  
Date datetime2(7),  
DimensionElement0Id int,
DimensionElement1Id int,
DimensionElement2Id int,
DimensionElement3Id int,
DimensionElement4Id int,
DimensionElement5Id int,
DimensionElement6Id int,
DimensionElement7Id int,
DimensionElement8Id int,
DimensionElement9Id int,
AverageRate decimal(28,10),
Text0 nvarchar(max),
Text1 nvarchar(max),
Text2 nvarchar(max),
Text3 nvarchar(max),
Text4 nvarchar(max),
Text5 nvarchar(max),
Text6 nvarchar(max),
Text7 nvarchar(max),
Text8 nvarchar(max),
Text9 nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO #ActualValuesLines(Amount, Date, DimensionElement0Id, DimensionElement1Id, DimensionElement2Id, DimensionElement3Id, DimensionElement4Id, DimensionElement5Id, DimensionElement6Id, DimensionElement7Id, DimensionElement8Id, DimensionElement9Id, AverageRate, Text0, Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5, Text6, Text7, Text8, Text9) 
SELECT Amount, Date, DimensionElement0Id, DimensionElement1Id, DimensionElement2Id, DimensionElement3Id, DimensionElement4Id, DimensionElement5Id, DimensionElement6Id, DimensionElement7Id, DimensionElement8Id, DimensionElement9Id, AverageRate, Text0, Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5, Text6, Text7, Text8, Text9 FROM x WHERE Text0 is NULL


SET @rowNo = 1
INSERT #ReportValues(Position, Col, Amount)
SELECT @rowNo, 'January', -ISNULL(Sum(Amount), 0)
FROM #ActualValuesLines ActualValuesLines
    LEFT JOIN DimensionElements LineName ON ActualValuesLines.DimensionElement4Id = LineName.Id
WHERE (LineName.Name = 'Goods')
    AND Year(ActualValuesLines.Date) = 2020 AND Month(ActualValuesLines.Date) =  1

INSERT #ReportValues(Position, Col, Amount)
SELECT @rowNo, 'Febuary', -ISNULL(Sum(Amount), 0)
FROM #ActualValuesLines ActualValuesLines
    LEFT JOIN DimensionElements LineName ON ActualValuesLines.DimensionElement4Id = LineName.Id
WHERE (LineName.Name = 'Goods')
    AND Year(ActualValuesLines.Date) = 2020 AND Month(ActualValuesLines.Date)= 2

...

SET @rowNo = 2
INSERT #ReportValues(Position, Col, Amount)
SELECT @rowNo, 'January', -ISNULL(Sum(Amount), 0)
FROM #ActualValuesLines ActualValuesLines
    LEFT JOIN DimensionElements LineName ON ActualValuesLines.DimensionElement4Id = LineName.Id
WHERE (LineName.Name = 'STTS')
    AND Year(ActualValuesLines.Date) = 2020 AND Month(ActualValuesLines.Date) =  1

INSERT #ReportValues(Position, Col, Amount)
SELECT @rowNo, 'Febuary', -ISNULL(Sum(Amount), 0)
FROM #ActualValuesLines ActualValuesLines
    LEFT JOIN DimensionElements LineName ON ActualValuesLines.DimensionElement4Id = LineName.Id
WHERE (LineName.Name = 'STTS')
    AND Year(ActualValuesLines.Date) = 2020 AND Month(ActualValuesLines.Date)= 2

...

SET @rowNo = 100
INSERT #ReportValues(Position, Col, Amount)
SELECT @rowNo, 'January', -ISNULL(Sum(Amount), 0)
FROM #ActualValuesLines ActualValuesLines
    LEFT JOIN DimensionElements LineName ON ActualValuesLines.DimensionElement4Id = LineName.Id
WHERE (LineName.Name = 'STTS')
    AND Year(ActualValuesLines.Date) = 2020 AND Month(ActualValuesLines.Date) =  1

INSERT #ReportValues(Position, Col, Amount)
SELECT @rowNo, 'Febuary', -ISNULL(Sum(Amount), 0)
FROM #ActualValuesLines ActualValuesLines
    LEFT JOIN DimensionElements LineName ON ActualValuesLines.DimensionElement4Id = LineName.Id
WHERE (LineName.Name = 'STTS')
    AND Year(ActualValuesLines.Date) = 2020 AND Month(ActualValuesLines.Date)= 2

SELECT Position, Col, Amount FROM #ReportValues
DROP TABLE #ReportValues
```

Comment: Your query is really too general.  Determine which query is causing the slowdown.  If it is *all* of them, then ask a *new* question about how to simplify the logic.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the logic is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your observation! The cause is those INSERT statements. I want to avoid to change the logic as much as possible. My first idea was to create an index for #ActualValuesLines but doesn't work.